# Elasticsearch copy index mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch cluster consisting of 6 nodes version 6 and we have an index called bishkek in the cluster, now I want to copy only the index mappings (no data) to the new index bishkek_v2

Answer (score 5):

Elasticsearch doesn't have any API that copy only mappings, so you would need to first get your mapping for **bishkek** index and create new index based on the mapping. To get the mapping you can run this `GET Request`.

```
GET /bishkek/_mapping
```

After getting the mapping you create your new Index:

```
PUT /bishkek_v2
{
  "mappings": {
  [Mapping you get from your old index]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this will help you to clone the index

```
POST /my_source_index/_clone/my_target_index
```

Comment: yeah, but i want to copy without data, mappings only